# Get two arrays from php files, compare them and export differencies to another array

Tags: php, arrays

I got two php files with `$_DATA` array and i want to compare the keys from both and create a new array (and file after) with the differencies (both keys and values).

These files got same and different keys, so the goal is to read all the keys, compare them and then create a new array with the custom keys in order to save them in a new php file.

I tried to read the files with `include`, *but i cant compare the arrays with the same `$_DATA` name.*

**Sample of array1**

```
$_DATA['key1'] = "value1";
$_DATA['key2'] = "value2";
$_DATA['key3'] = "value3";
$_DATA['key4'] = "value4";
$_DATA['key5'] = "value5";
$_DATA['key6'] = "value6";
```

**Sample of array2**

```
$_DATA['key1'] = "value1";
$_DATA['key2'] = "value2";
$_DATA['custom_key1'] = "value9";
$_DATA['custom_key2'] = "value10";
$_DATA['key3'] = "value3";
$_DATA['custom_key3'] = "value12";
```

**Expected array1**

```
$_DATA['key1'] = "value1";
$_DATA['key2'] = "value2";
$_DATA['key3'] = "value3";
$_DATA['key4'] = "value4";
$_DATA['key5'] = "value5";
$_DATA['key6'] = "value6";
```

**Expected array2**

```
$_DATA['custom_key1'] = "value9";
$_DATA['custom_key2'] = "value10";
$_DATA['custom_key3'] = "value11";
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You should copy the data array to a new variable before you include the second file. But if you use these arrays as a permanent storage for data you might want to look into other solutions like databases, config files, etc.

Comment: Load the array inside a function call (so that the scope is limited) and copy them each to a single instance of an array (for example via a class instance attribute, a static array or a global variable).

Comment: So what's the expected result here, and why?

Comment: @jeroen i thought about storage but i want to store them in file as a copy of the php file. I'll look into passing the first array with a new name.

Comment: @deceze the result is to create a new array with only the different keys and values, so i can create a new php file with the custom data after i compare them with the original (first) file. Its 5k array keys

Comment: Update your question and *show* us the expected result. All your keys and values are different, so it's unclear what exactly you want.

Comment: I hope you did look at [`array_diff_key`](http://php.net/array_diff_key)...!?

Comment: Changing the `$_DATA` name of the second array (like `%_DATA2`) but not in file, should let me `array_diff()` them. But i'm trying to find how to change it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example in kind of pseudocode:

```
class load_and_compare {
    $arrays = array();

    function load($filename) {
        include($filename);
        $arrays[] = $_DATA;
    }

    function compare() {
        // return something like array_diff_keys($this->arrays[0], $this->arrays[1]);
    }
}

$ll = new load_and_compare();
$ll->load('file_a.php');
$ll->load('file_b.php');
$output = $ll->compare();
```

As far as the comparison function supports it, this can be used for any number of input files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I followed your approach and after some edits i get `Undefined offset: 0` in `function compare()`, when i'm trying to pass `json_decode($this->arrays[0])`. At `$output = $ll->compare();` says `void method 'compare' result used`.

Comment: The idea was that you replace the comment with some comparison code that is suitable for your needs...

Comment: Thats what i did. I tried to test is with the one array to see that its ok, before setting the function right.